# Sending recorded accelerometer values to server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, post, accelerometer

i want to send the accelerometer values recorded for 5 seconds to server.i tried to concatenate the values and send through http post request but it is not working.
since almost 350 values are recorded the data is large and is not possible send through http post.
is there a method through which i can send the values?
i use servlets(Google App Engine )on the server  side.

Comment: app engine does not support FTP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) 
It will create an [RPC](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/) api, just call the GAE using method calles. I dont know the limitation but might be worse looking into

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem, since its the device that's sending the data :)

All in all you can:

1. Zip the contents and send it - compressed version
2. You can open a dedicated 'BufferedOutputStream' and Server can listen to it in 'BufferedInputStream' and listen to it dedicatedly
3. Send it in parts, with some ID to identify the parts and later assemble them

Comment: values must be sent in real time.can you explain how is this done

Comment: The open a dedicated connection and post them in real time to server. The second approach